# C# Crystal Report export "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: c#, web-services, crystal-reports

I am hosting a web service in IIS on a server machine.  I am trying to export pdf files to a network path using Crystal Reports API.  The export works fine from my local machine.  I use a different path depending on where my code is executing.

From local machine I just need to use `\\dmzisilon\` however from server machine, I need to use `\\dmzisilon.x.com\`

The web service is locking up after this call:

```
doc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"\\dmzisilon.x.com\Test\03811Z.pdf");
```

Using (x.com) to keep company name private.

Getting exception:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I can browse to `\\dmzisilon.x.com\Test\` just fine.  I can even create new files here from the server.

If I run the web service locally and invoke the call to debug, it exports just fine.

I added in this call here just to verify within code that the path does exist:

```
if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(exportFileName)))
```

It verifies that the path DOES exist.

I don't know what else to try at this point.  The exception being thrown isn't much help.

Thanks.

P.S. `document.Load(@"\\dmzisilon.x.com\Reports\flyerrpt.rpt");` works using a network path if that makes any difference.

EDIT: Here's a stacktrace if this helps anyone.

```
  <StackFrame Index="4">
    <FileName />
    <Method>Void ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType, System.String)</Method>
    <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
    <ColumnNumber>0</ColumnNumber>
    <ILOffset>151</ILOffset>
  </StackFrame>
  <StackFrame Index="3">
    <FileName />
    <Method>Void Export(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportRequestContext)</Method>
    <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
    <ColumnNumber>0</ColumnNumber>
    <ILOffset>99</ILOffset>
  </StackFrame>
  <StackFrame Index="2">
    <FileName />
    <Method>System.IO.Stream ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportRequestContext)</Method>
    <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
    <ColumnNumber>0</ColumnNumber>
    <ILOffset>389</ILOffset>
  </StackFrame>
  <StackFrame Index="1">
    <FileName />
    <Method>System.IO.Stream ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportRequestContext)</Method>
    <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
    <ColumnNumber>0</ColumnNumber>
    <ILOffset>794</ILOffset>
  </StackFrame>
  <StackFrame Index="0">
    <FileName />
    <Method>System.Object Export(CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ExportOptions, CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.RequestContext)</Method>
    <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
    <ColumnNumber>0</ColumnNumber>
    <ILOffset>-1</ILOffset>
  </StackFrame>
```

Comment: Does the account that is running IIS have the rights to write in the network path?

Comment: How can I tell what account is running IIS?  Is that the application pool identity?

Comment: Yes, it is. (ignore this, is just to reach 15 characters)

Comment: Sorry it took me a few days to respond.  It just has ApplicationPoolIdentity so I guess the user it's using is DefaultAppPool.  I do not see that user as an option when adding permissions through the security tab for the network folder.

Comment: I added in some code to write a simple text document to the location and the text document was able to write with no exceptions.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was not using the IP address:Port for the crystal connection info.  I was just using the servername as if it were inside the domain.